# Using socket.io and node.js how do I access my server on EC2 AWS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I am running socket.io and node.js, on my local computer under `localhost` everything worked perfectly. I'm trying to figure out how to run it on a new ec2 server but don't exactly know where to start. I saw another question that involved a C# server and setting up a security group? But it doesn't exactly relate to Socket.io.

I'm wondering specifically what IP I should be connecting to, and also my ports are completely open just in case for the time being to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Does your ec2 instance have a server installed (Apache, nginx, etc.) and configured?

Comment: No, I guess I assumed the instance did that.

Comment: Just installed Apache and started it

Comment: Great, now launch your node.js app on the Apache server. Have you done that before?

Comment: No, but I cannot get apache to actually run at all. I followed the AWS guide to get the server to even start, it returns [OK] but when I try to connect to the public DNS, it returns "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: So you can hit the IP directly but the domain isn't working?

Comment: @MatthewWalker make sure you create a 'security group' which exposes the HTTP port 80  (or modify the default one so it does).

Comment: Also, if you'd like to skip the DevOps process you can have all this stuff done for you with AWS Elastic Beanstalk or AWS LightSail

Comment: Can't hit IP or domain, but i'll check into Beanstalk and LightSail

Comment: Checked into Bitnami Lightsail and that worked perfect, you should add that as an answer, thank you!